# how to put a condition for mat date picker if it is less than 18 years need to show text box angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, mat-datepicker

I am trying to show text field based on the age validation if the age is less than 18 then only mat input field (Test box should appear)

Here is my current code

```
            <form [formGroup]="form">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"
            formControlName="pickerCtl">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Guardian Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="guardianName" class="form-control" placeholder="Guardian Name">
            <span class="fa fa-lock lock_field"></span>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label>Guardian Contact No</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="guardianContactNo" class="form-control" placeholder="Guardian Contact No">
              <span class="fa fa-lock lock_field"></span>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Currently i was able to set datepicker to select date from 1900 till a current day before

Here is my TS

```
    minDate = new Date(1900, 0, 1);
    maxDate =  new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))
```

Please find [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-ang?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html) URL

Comment: can you explain more about your use-case ?

Comment: If I add this date `5/19/2001` then what would be expected output ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda from that date to todaydate we have to calculate the years if it is 12 years we have to show the guardian details

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thanks for the reply hope you got my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf` to show/hide form-fields. Create a method in your component to determine if guardian should be visible. Something like this:

```
  get showGuardian(): boolean {
    const date = new Date().setFullYear(this.maxDate.getFullYear() - 18);
    return this.form.get('pickerCtl').value?.getTime() > date;
  }
```

And add an `*ngIf` to your mat-form-field in the template:

```
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="showGuardian">
    ..
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer that ngif i need to put for all two mat field right

Comment: You can also create a ng-container or a div element around both form fields and at the *ngIf to that element.

Comment: initially do i need to set the showGuardian as true / false in top of my code

Comment: by default itself text box is coming

Comment: i haev updated here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-ang?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

Comment: You fill the initial value of your date field with the current date. So this matches the criteria and the fields will be visible. Don't add an initial value if you don't want the fields to be visible initially.

Comment: can you please update my stackblitz it will be really helpful

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-ang-b5c7ke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232610/discussion-between-mr-m-and-felix).